# Regularity of Checking for plugin updates?

Tags: plugins, updates

How often does the word press core check wordpress.org for plug in updates? Is it once a day or more? Is checking for updates triggered by some action or filter?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 cron events which checks for the updates 
1) wp_version_check 
2) wp_update_plugins 
3) wp_update_themes

These runs twice a day, if you want to see about their occurrence you can install [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) and check these.